# How to animate a flashing UIView until a stop button is pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am trying to make a UIView flash a certain color until a stop button is pressed.

Any help in doing so would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you explain a little more, and show some code that you tried?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/603977)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the animation methods of UIView. Specifically look at methods like `animateWithDuration:animations:` and variants. The variants with options are what you want. There are options to repeat and/or auto-reverse the animation.

### EDIT:

Actually, if you want the color to flash rather than cross-fade between colors then using a `UIView` animation might not be the best choice. That's going to cause smooth transitions between colors.

If you want the color to flash from one color to the next you might be better off using a timer and simply setting the background color.

I created a simple custom subclass of `UIView` that has a variable `animateColor`. Set it to true and it creates a timer that cycles through an array of background colors. Use 2 colors if you want it to cycle back and forth between colors. Use more if desired.

```
public class LiveView: UIView {
  
  //Adjust this interval value if desired to get a different flash interval.
  //Note that changing the interval will have no effect while the timer is running.
  public var interval = 0.5
  
  //Change the array of colors if you want different colors
  public var backgroundColors = [UIColor.gray, UIColor.green, UIColor.blue, UIColor.red]
  var colorIndex = 0
  

  //Set this flag to true to animate between the colors. Set it to false to stop the animation.
  public var animateColor: Bool = false {
    didSet {
      if animateColor {
        colorTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: true, block: {
          timer in
          self.colorIndex = (self.colorIndex + 1) % self.backgroundColors.count
          self.setColor()
        })
      } else {
        colorTimer?.invalidate()
      }
    }
  }
  private weak var colorTimer: Timer?

  func setColor() {
    backgroundColor = backgroundColors[colorIndex]
  }
  
  public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setColor()
  }

  public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setColor()
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, why the down-vote? I don't think it's appropriate to provide code for vague "can you help me" questions, but pointing a new dev in the right direction seems like it would be helpful.